# Clockwork package installer stopped

Tags: android, wear-os

Recently, I've been coding an APP which could work for an Android Device and an Android Wearable. 
Today, I finished developments, and I've created a production APK following http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html tutorial.

However, when I install APK on a device, it works, but it doesn't get pushed to device.

Device crashes with message:

[image]

This is the stacktrace returned by Wearable:

```
08-04 21:53:47.957      914-914/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller, PID: 914
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:187)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:106)
        at java.util.jar.StrictJarFile.<init>(StrictJarFile.java:65)
        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectManifestDigest(PackageParser.java:594)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getPackageInfo(PackageUtil.java:76)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerService.installPackage(PackageInstallerService.java:144)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerService.access$000(PackageInstallerService.java:29)
        at com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerService$1.handleMessage(PackageInstallerService.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't really know how to debug this.

APP works perfectly when pushed via ADB.

Tell me if you do need any further info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Today it worked.

What did I do:

- Clean
- Removed old APK generated (.....\mobile\build\outputs\apk)
- Compile via gradle via script "assembleRelease"

Now it works.